# Animation in ListView (Commonsware touchListView)

Tags: android, android-listview, commonsware-cwac

I try to show an animation (a windmills) inside each view of the ListView adapter, I can see the first image of the animation but the "animation" won't start.

Inside the adapter when I build the row, I start the animation like that:

```
           ImageView img = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.loader);
           img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           img.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.myanim);
           AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) img.getBackground();
           frameAnimation.start();
```

The animation myanim.xml work when it used outside a listview...

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using `setBackgroundResource()` instead of `setImageResource()`?

Comment: if I use  img.setImageResource(R.drawable.myanim); and AnimationDrawable frameAnimation = img.getDrawable(); it<s the same result.

Comment: You might try switching to a plain `ListView` briefly to see if it works there. If it does, then it's a problem specific to `TouchListView`. If it fails with a plain `ListView`..., um, I have no idea. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Actually Animation works when you are using event listeners.like button click.

Try to create button and give a

Button button=new Button();

button.performClick();

In Onclick method you have to start animation..